# TLinkLabel with Transparent Background in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

how to make the background of the TLinkLabel transparent or exactly as background color ( i am using a custom TPNG background ) ?

Comment: The standard TLinkLabel **is** transparent.

Comment: yes, that's what I said in your previous question. I'd guess the problem is your custom background.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with the standard TLinkLabel transparency too. I now use [TJvLinkLabel](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help%3aTJvLinkLabel) from JEDI JVCL. In my experience, it handles transparency much better.

Comment: `TLinkLabel` works beautifully for me in my quick trial with link label on top of `TImage`.